# End Command When First Empty Cell Found

Tags: vba, excel

This code is used to look through a list of values, and the code needs to end at the first blank row. Currently, this code causes an error when a blank cell is encountered. Not sure how to end command when it hits a blank cell. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
Sub PMN_Update()

 Dim Month As String
 Dim Year As String
 Dim File As String
 Dim FileRow As String
 Dim x As Variant


Month = Range("G2").Value
Year = Range("G3").Value

NumFiles = Application.CountA(Sheets("PMNs").Range("A2:A200"))

ChDir "L:\management tools\PROJECT\Prog_Fcst"


For x = 1 To NumFiles
    FileRow = "A" & 1 + x

    File = Range(FileRow).Text

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & File, _
    UpdateLinks:=0
    Sheets("Initiation").Select
    Range("Q4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Month
    Range("Q5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Year

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.Run "'" & File & "'!UpdateMaterial"
    Application.Run "'" & File & "'!UpdateAMRData"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.Run UpdateMaterial
    'Application.Run UpdateAMRData

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use this `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo 99` and add another line after `Next x` as `99 Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Masoud Sorry for lack of context...original post updated. This code is used to look through a list of values, and the code needs to end at the first blank row.

Comment: What is the meaning of the "AAAAA..." at the end of your question?

Comment: You can wither use `While Your_Reference <> ""` instead of  for-loop or use the other option that I provided in the first comment (it has been edited. take a look at it).

Comment: @CallumDA Just threw a bunch of As in there to get around Stack's minimum text requirement...it kept blocking my post because it was mostly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options for handling this:

First method can be using `While`

```
  While Cells(x + 1, "A").Value <> "" 'this check if it is empty
   'YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  x = x + 1
  Wend
```

Second is using `On Error`:

You can either use this 
`On Error Resume Next` 
or
`On Error GoTo 99` 
and add a line after next before the `End Sub` as this: `99 Exit Sub`

Third is using an if-statement as other users provided.

I personally like the first approach.

Comment: The downside of using an `On Error` is that **all** errors will be trapped by it, not just errors caused by the cell being blank.  `On Error` should be used as a last resort when there is no other way of testing for the error before encountering it - and testing for a blank cell is easily done by other methods.

Comment: @YowE3K Yeah. That's why I like the first approach. But depending on the purpose of your macro that downside can be what you want (Unlikely if you want to debug the errors).

Answer (score 2):

Just do an `Exit Sub` or an `End` when you encounter a blank cell:

```
For x = 1 To NumFiles
    If IsEmpty(Cells(x + 1, "A").Value) Then End
```

Or you could base your test on the value of `File`:

```
    File = Range(FileRow).Text
    If File = "" Then End
```

Comment: Actually this answer is wrong. `If IsEmpty(Cells(x + 1, "A").Value) Then End` here you also exclude `x` because `x+1` is empty.

Comment: @Masoud - The OP is using a loop from `1 To NumFiles` but, when `x` is 1 they are looking at the information in row 2 of the worksheet.  That's why the `FileRow = "A" & 1 + x` statement is doing the `1 + x`.  It's the same reason why your `While` is doing the `x + 1`.

Comment: Got you. But I like the second if-statement better since it is explicitly check the File. Thanks for clarification and sorry for the wrong comment.

Comment: @Masoud Personally, I like the second statement better myself, but the first one ties up closer to the way the OP phrased the question, i.e. "how to end command when it hits a blank cell", so it seemed better to show how to turn that statement in the question into a statement in code.